# Spacing between lines of <dt><dd> tags

Tags: html, css, forms, css-float

Before you read, note this. I'd love to put the pointy brackets <> around dd, dl, and dt, but unfortunately, the page is reading them as actual HTML code, not text. Please bear with me.

I have a problem with the dl, dt, and dd tags in HTML. I am designing a questionnaire of sorts. I have the question/caption in the dt tag, and then the HTML form questions(E.G. select or input)  between the dd tags. I have the question/caption dt aligned next to the corresponding form dd using float: left on the dt tag. This is working fine. However, my problem is this: I would like a line break between the rows. This is an approximation of my current code:
Each line has **a dt and dd tag aligned side-by-side** using a float attribute on the dt tag.

```
<dl>
    <dt class='list-item'>Question 1</dt>
    <dd class='list-item'> <input type='text' maxlength='3'> </dd>
    <br />
    <dt class='list-item'> Question 2</dt>
    <dd class='list-item'> 
    <select required>
    <option value='one'> choice1</option>
    <option value='two'> choice1</option>
    </select>
    </dd> 
</dl>
```

and the CSS

```
.list-item{
margin-left: 5%;
width: 45%
}
dt{
float: left;
text-align: center;
}
```

My problem is this: The two lines (each with one question and one answer) do not have the desired spacing. I have tried adding the margin-bottom CSS attribute to the dt tag, and it just messed it up. Any suggestions to put spacing between the two lines? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xhof1gew/) ?

Comment: Actually for me it's working well [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xhof1gew/2/), I suggest you to check for other css properties that may be overriding it.

Comment: @divy3993 you missed where I said the question and it's respective form were on the same line, so if i just specify top for dt, it messes it up.

Comment: Ok @Mr. Chameleon, Check the answer now, still any issues tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might helps you:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xhof1gew/3/)

```css
.list-item {
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 45%
}
dt,dd{
display:table-cell;
margin:0px 5px;
}
dt{
float: left;
text-align: center;
border:1px solid #333; /*Remove this it's just for checking space it leaves */ 
}
```

```html
<dl> <dt class='list-item'>Question 1</dt>

    <dd class='list-item'>
        <input type='text' maxlength='3' />
    </dd>
    <br /> <dt class='list-item'> Question 2</dt>

    <dd class='list-item'>
        <select required>
            <option value='one'>choice1</option>
            <option value='two'>choice1</option>
        </select>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Ya display:table-cell, it's the one.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just give each `dt` some top margin?

```css
.list-item {
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 45%
}
dt {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<dl> <dt class='list-item'>Question 1</dt>

  <dd class='list-item'>
    <input type='text' maxlength='3' />
  </dd>
  
  <dt class='list-item'> Question 2</dt>
  <dd class='list-item'>
    <select required>
      <option value='one'>choice1</option>
      <option value='two'>choice1</option>
    </select>
  </dd>
  
</dl>
```

EDIT: Apparently I missed the requirement that each `dt/dd` combo should be on one line.

```css
dl {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
dt, dd {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background:lightblue
  
}
```

```html
<dl> <dt class='list-item'>Question 1</dt>

  <dd class='list-item'>
    <input type='text' maxlength='3' />
  </dd>
  
  <dt class='list-item'> Question 2</dt>
  <dd class='list-item'>
    <select required>
      <option value='one'>choice1</option>
      <option value='two'>choice1</option>
    </select>
  </dd>
  
</dl>
```

Comment: you missed where I said that the dt is next to its corresponding dd so giving the dt a margin-top messes it up.

Comment: no. One question and form per line. So at this point two lines. The first one with the first question and first form; the next one with the second question and second form.